# In App Purchase - when apple Id is changed, the old products still for new user

Tags: ios

I am Implementing In app purchase, and I am only checking the local receipt on the device
and right now I have a scenario while testing in sandbox
so If the receipt contain the product and not expired I will allow the new user to see the feature.
steps
user 1 -> login(appleID) -> buy products -> then logout (appleId)
user 2 -> login (new apple ID) -> found the purchased products as the local receipt contains it

How can I fix this issue and
can I check that the user(apple Id) is changed and then delete the certificate ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. Your app has no visibility of the purchasing Apple ID, and what does it matter?  The subscription was purchased on that device and they are accessing it on that device

Comment: Thanks, Paulw11 for the answer, but right now the apple ID which buys the feature, can restore it in several devices. so it is somehow a hack, to buy it once and use it for several users.

Comment: Ok, so that is a slightly different question to the one you asked.  You can only solve this problem if the user has an account in your app; You can then store the original purchase transaction identifier against their account on your backend.  If they try and activate the same purchase on a different backend account then you either deny it or transfer the subscription from the first account to the second.

Comment: actually the user has no account in the app, Is there another way ?

Comment: No. Your user is anonymous so you cannot link the purchase to them